# How do I filter an array object with multiple filterBy values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to filter an array object with array value.

```
const arrayData = [
  {
    name: 'abc',
    designation: 'senior',
    phone: '3589234556',
    address: 'Address 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'pqr',
    designation: 'junior',
    phone: '',
    address: 'Address 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'xyz',
    designation: 'senior',
    phone: '3589234557',
    address: ''
  }
]

const filterBy = ['senior','junior', 'missing_contact_info']
```

Note: 'missing_contact_info' means if the 'phone' or 'address' is empty or null

Expected conditions:-

condition1: `senior`

condition2: `senior+junior`

condition3: `senior+junior+missing_contact_info`

condition4: `senior+missing_contact_info`

.
.
.
etc

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: @ashishsingh I tried with `arrayData.filter(el => !filterBy.includes(el.designation))`but not sure how to achieve with `missing_contact_info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my solution to your problem

```
const subresult = arrayData.filter(c=>filterBy.includes(c.designation));

var result;
if (filterBy.includes('missing_contact_info')) {
    result = subresult.filter(c=> !c.phone || !c.address);
}
else 
{
   result = subresult;
}
```

Comment: What about `missing_contact_info`?

Comment: into filter() you are inserting a function where you can add multiple conditions, i will update my example right now